# Determine location at the position of mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, media-queries

I am putting together a tool that allows people to double click and leave messages anywhere on a HTML page using jQuery. It have hit a stumbling block to do with positioning of the messages.

The code I am testing at the moment:

```
$('body').bind('dblclick', function(e) {

    var message = $('<div class="message">Form here</div>').css({
        'left' : e.pageX,
        'top'  : e.pageY
    });

    $(this).append(message);
});
```

This creates a new 'message' at the position of the mouse click. While this works to an extent, as soon as the browser window is resized the 'message' moves out of position. As I am eventually hoping to save the messages (and retrieve them) it is not ideal to have them load in a different locations for every user on every browser. I want the messages to attach to the page layout even if that page uses media queries.

My understanding of the problem is that I need to position the messages relative to the nearest element where the user has clicked. The question is. How do I this?

Any tips or hints would be greatly appreciated.

**Update 04/07/11**

Most of the answers I have had below are not really what I am after. I have uploaded an [example of my page to JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sqctx/) to show you my setup. The problem here is making the messages attach in a relative position, so that as the browser window is re-sized the messages move along with the content.

For example. If I attach a message to the second paragraph on a page how do I get that message to stick with that paragraph, regardless of browser/device width. As far as I can tell I need to establish the nearest block level element (or element with an ID or class) that can be used to position the message relative to.

Hope that clears up the question & thanks for all your suggestions.

Comment: Ignore my answer, my dicklexic arse didn't read the question properly. What you'd want to do is insert the cross element into the upper most element on the HTML page. Instead of calculating the X and Y from the browser, you'd do it from this upper most element and this should mean that the box moves on resize.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, there are potentially several problems: the first that I can see is you need to make sure that the "body" element covers the whole page, because it will only extend as far as its box allows it to. (i realise normally, simply setting the background of a div usually lets you see its extent, but the body tag is a special case. Its background extends to the entire visible area of the browser, but it's box may not)

Secondly, it is important to set the css "position" property to "absolute" or absolute positioning won't work: This code works:

```
    $('body').bind('dblclick', function(e){

        var message = $('<div class="message">Form here</div>').css({
            'position' : 'absolute',
            'left' : e.pageX,
            'top'  : e.pageY
        });

        $(this).append(message);
    });
```

Comment: Hi Tom. Thanks for your answer. I forgot to mention that the messages are already positioned absolute using CSS. The problem is that re-sizing the browser window with items positioned absolute causes the content to move and the messages to stay in a fixed position. I am trying to make sure the messages remain in context with the page content at all times. The only way to achieve this in my mind is with a relative position to the content that has just been clicked. This is the true issue here.

Comment: i'm assuming you have some kind of central div, which is given a width, then has it's "margin-left" and "margin-right" properties set to auto to allow it to remain central.  This then means that as the window is resized horizontally, your absolutely positioned divs "slide" left accross your central div? If this is the case, then you should append to the div, not to body, and yes, relative should do the trick I think, though it might be relative to the position the box WOULD have been in, rather than relative to the position of the parent's box. I'll look it up and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

This should shows how to track mouse movements http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position#How_do_I_find_the_mouse_position.3F

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).mousemove(function(e){
      $('#status').html(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);
   }); 
})
```

along with this you may use `resize()` to change position of div

```
 $(window).resize(function() {
  $('body').prepend('<div>' + $(window).width() + '</div>');
});
```

Comment: Hi Prashant. My code is already tracking mouse position. The question is a little more complex.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest placing a single `div` on your page, with fixed width and height. Then apply your `dblclick` function to that `div` rather than the `body`.

You may also want to position the dynamic `div` elements absolutely, so they appear in the correct positions. Here is an [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pWqEQ/).

Comment: Hi James. As I want this to work on any web page I think it will be difficult to me to limit the canvas where messages can be placed. Perhaps wrapping the body in a div that is 100% on the width and height will do the trick... you may have just given me an idea on what I can try!

Answer (score 0):

You need to position the message div:

```
$('body').bind('dblclick', function(e) {

    var message = $('<div class="message">Form here</div>').css({
        'left' : e.pageX,
        'top'  : e.pageY,
        'position' : 'fixed',
        'zIndex': 999999
    });

    $(this).append(message);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PvFTN/

Comment: Hi AlienWebguy. Unfortunately position fixed does not solve the issue for me. The content still moves independently of the messages - scrolling breaks the behaviour I am looking for.